# Why does DisplayInformation.RawPixelsPerViewPixel = .83 for Windows 8.1 apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, screen-resolution, uwp

When I run my Windows 8.1 targeted app in Windows 10, `RawPixelsPerViewPixel=0.83` and everything is slightly scaled down.

If I target the same app to Windows 10 (create a Universal Windows App), then `RawPixelsPerViewPixel=1` and everything is slightly larger.

`DisplayInformation.LogicalDpi` also changes from 79.63 to 96 when I switch between the Windows 8.1 and Universal Windows App.

The app looks better on Windows 10 if it is scaled to .83, and I want to re-target to Windows 10 for the new APIs. I don't want to have to resize everything though. Is there anyway to control or change this value? How is it calculated and why does it change?

I want to continue supporting Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. Currently I'm going through and externalizing all of the widths/heights/margins/fonts so the Windows 8.1 target can remain the same size while I manually reduce the size of everything in the Windows 10 target. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running it on a Windows 10 VM. After running it on a normal Windows 10 installation, the 8.1 app is not auto-resized and doesn't have a weird `RawPixelsPerViewPixel` or `LogicalDpi`. I'm just going to chalk it up to the VM.

Comment: I've noticed that my app running on Win 10 on a certain machine does not display the same as under Win 8. I am in this case comparing two physical machines, running Win 8 and Win 10 with identical screen resolutions. I think there was a similar question asked a while ago (I can't find it) and the conclusion there was that it had to do with screen resolution. On lower resolution screens (1366x768) the displays are different between the two Windows versions. On higher resolution screens, the apps look the same.